# Django channels and nginx - error during handshake

Tags: django, nginx, django-channels

I'm trying to deploy a Django/Django Channels application to a VPS. The django part of the project works, i can visit any url and the templates are loading, but the Django Channels part of it doesn't work. Whenever i try to reach the websocket i either get `connection refused` or `WebSocket connection to 'ws://54.39.20.155/receiver' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404`

Can someone help me find what i'm doing wrong and tell me what do i need to do in order to run Django Channels?

Here is my setup:

Environment:

```
virtualenv
django
django-channels
gunicorn
nginx
systemd
```

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject**

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 54.39.20.155;

        location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
        location /static/ {
            root /WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoom/WaitingRoom/static;
        }

        location / {
            include proxy_params;
            proxy_pass http://unix:/WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoomEnv.sock;
        }
    }
```

**/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoom
ExecStart=/WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoomEnv/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoomEnv.sock WR.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To start gunicorn: `sudo systemctl start gunicorn`
To start nginx: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

Comment: how are you running channels? your `WR.wsgi:application` is the normal django views

Comment: Yes, indeed i had to add another systemd service to run Daphne, it should be working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to your nginx.conf

```
location /receiver {
    proxy_pass http://unix:/WaitingRoomVenv/WaitingRoomEnv.sock;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```